# How to change the content of a div after a period of time with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

working with laravel 5.4 and trying to change the content of a div after period of time, on the other words, want to change/refresh the content of a div when any changes comes to the database records by ajax.(something like notification) is there any way to do this? How?

Comment: how can you get that an update has been made to the database to trigger ajax?

Comment: There are two ways to do this, by socket programming, or by calling the ajax on a regular interval

Comment: That depends, is it a one time event or are you planning to refresh the contents at some particular intervals of time continuously ?

Comment: if you want the server to initiate the update then your only option realistically is to use websockets. If you use ajax the browser has to initiate the update, and it doesn't know if an update has actually been made, so all it can do is just request the latest data, whatever that happens to be. You can set it to run on an interval so it just keeps on asking, but don't ask too often or you'll just have performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you guys, i found the answer. here is what i want:

```
setInterval(function(){ someFunction(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Using this code how could you know that database is updated/changed?

Comment: this will simply call a function after set of interval ie: 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can try below example code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "main.php",
    error: function(){
       // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
   success: function(){
      //do something
   },
   timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

Please also read [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)